# Windows command line tool for disk IO monitoring

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, performance-monitoring, windows-command-prompt, performance-counters

I am looking at extracting disk IO statistics on Windows 2003 upon occurrence of some events, e.g. a long full GC occurring that is waiting a long time for CPU resource. I have read that Process Explorer allows you to do that, but it is a GUI based application, which entails that you must know when the problem will occur again and you a must already be logged into your server. However, because I do not know when it will happen, I need to write a script to output disk IO statistics when the last GC took more than x seconds.

Are there any such command line tools already available out there, such that I can simply call that program to output the results for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the exact type of data you are trying to collect, but all perfmon counter data is available via the [`typeperf` command line utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753182.aspx) even in Server 2003.

#### Sample use

List counters available (without instances):

```
typeperf -q
```

sample total CPU usage over 10 seconds once and return:

```
typeperf "Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -si 10 -sc 1
```

In general, all counters available through the perfmon GUI are also available through typeperf by the same name. Note that names [may be localised](http://blogs.splunk.com/2013/06/17/windows-perfmon-and-internationalization/) on non-MUI systems.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is good, but its example is for processor, not disk IO. Here
is one for that:

```sh
typeperf -si 2 "\LogicalDisk(_Total)\Disk Bytes/sec"
```