# Windows Server Command Line for Remotly Measure Data Disk IOPS,CPU,RAM Monitoring

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, performance, performance-monitoring

I want to measure data usage like IOPS, CPU, RAM ,Capacity ,Bandwidth ETC from Remote Server.

I [**Know**](https://serverfault.com/questions/767485/windows-command-line-tool-for-disk-io-monitoring), that it is possible to measure it localy with the `Typeperf` Command.

However, again, i want to measure that data from Remote Server and export it to csv -in one command.

I want the results to display like that in CSV:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typeperf support remote server monitoring with parameter:

```
 -s "Remote Server"
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/typeperf

Comment: That's great but i actually looking for one command line that include all the parameters above: IOPS,CPU,RAM etc